# Finding or searching the index number in Pandas Data?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2], 'col2':[3,4]})
myseries = df['col1']
myseries[myseries == 2]
1    2
dtype: int64
myseries[myseries == 2].index[0]
1
```

Is this the best code we can get? If you have better than this please send us tip!

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly do you want to achieve or improve in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `.loc` or `.iloc`:

```
myseries.loc[0]
myseries.iloc[0]
```

[iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) is index-based whereas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) is label based.

Both methods are the preferred way of selecting data in a pandas dataframe or series.